# javascript regexp fails in firefox

Tags: javascript, css, regex, background-image

I was developing regexp in chrome and everything worked fine... then i tried the same webpage in firefox (for ubuntu v 20) and saw this: `TypeError: imageName is null`.
I couldn't find the reason. 
here is my code:
bg is something like `http://localhost:3000/images/gallery/905/thumb/905.jpg`

```
 bg =  $('div.image',Clicked).css('background-image')
    bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
    console.log('bg')
    console.log(bg)
    var imageNameRegexp = /\/([0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{3,4})$/i
    var imageName =  bg.match(imageNameRegexp)
    var imageLocation = '/images/gallery/'+imageName[1]+'/large_croped/'+imageName[1]+imageName[2];
       console.log(imageLocation);
    $('#big_project_image').css('background-image','url("' + imageLocation+'")');
```

What it does:
It takes background-image property of one div, parses it, gets image name & extension. assigns to the other div bigger version of that image.
Why is that?

Comment: `imagename` is being assigned the result returned from a `String.match()` call and this will be `null` when `bg` does not match the regex. This code does not check for this possibility then (erroneously in the case for a non-match) goes on and accesses elements of the match (i.e. `imageName[1]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change regexp to include quotes at the end `"?'?`. firefox includes quotes in the property value
`var imageNameRegexp = /\/([0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{3,4})"?'?$/i`